# What is the difference between an engine, environment, and system in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, system

I'm using Xcode and want to desperately know what exactly is the difference between an engine, environment, and system. for example, before I can get the console to work properly and run my code the "system" has to find a main method inside my project folder in my computer file system. is the Xcode environment the same as the System or are they two different IDLE components? thank you.

Comment: The words you're asking about are not ones with single definitions.  Especially "system" is used for almost anything that has more than one part.  You need to supply more context for where you're getting these words.  (In your specific example, the C or Objective-C runtime finds `main` inside your linked application and uses it as the starting point for executing your code.  Source files and folders mean very little when talking about native executables.)

Comment: C (and its relatives) are languages that are typically compiled and linked into native code, as opposed to languages like Perl and others that are usually interpreted from source.  The first thoughts to come to mind about "why" are optimization and packaging.

Comment: so far I been able to breakdown the "system" (in context) as being the OS. OS calls main method and all lines inside of it get executed. why does the runtime have to look for a main method inside my linked application? isn't writing main in the editor enough for it to start executing the program?  thank you